# Algolia search causing heroku app crash

Tags: node.js, firebase, heroku, algolia

I am trying to use algolia search on a heroku server.
It works fine locally. However when it is loaded onto heroku it crashes giving this result:

```
 /app/dist/algolia/algolia-manager.js:28
2017-05-15T17:40:19.948991+00:00 app[web.1]:                 throw err;
2017-05-15T17:40:19.948991+00:00 app[web.1]:                 ^
2017-05-15T17:40:19.948996+00:00 app[web.1]: AlgoliaSearchNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND bzkq9hqh2-1.algolianet.com bzkq9hqh2-1.algolianet.com:443
2017-05-15T17:40:19.948998+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ClientRequest.error (/app/node_modules/algoliasearch/src/server/builds/node.js:227:14)
2017-05-15T17:40:19.948998+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:292:16)
2017-05-15T17:40:19.948998+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
2017-05-15T17:40:19.948999+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-15T17:40:19.949000+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:309:9)
2017-05-15T17:40:19.949000+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
2017-05-15T17:40:19.949001+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
2017-05-15T17:40:19.949001+00:00 app[web.1]:     at connectErrorNT (net.js:1021:8)
2017-05-15T17:40:19.949002+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
2017-05-15T17:40:19.949002+00:00 app[web.1]:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

This happens with the simple example hosted [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/integrations/firebase-algolia/).
Does anybody know how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your APPID is missing one character, that's why you are seeing this error.

Comment: Thanks the problem was that the APPID in the environment var on heroku was incorrect. It worked once I fixed it